Leaflet-GPX plugin not finding start point despite successful GPX load
I'm working on a web application that displays GPX routes on a map using Leaflet and the Leaflet-GPX plugin. I'm encountering an issue where the get_start_point() method is not available on the GPX object, despite the GPX file seemingly loading successfully.
Here's the relevant part of my code:
new L.GPX(gpxData, {
    async: true,
    // ... marker options ...
}).on('loaded', function(e) {
    var gpx = e.target;
    console.log('GPX object:', gpx);
    console.log('GPX methods:', Object.keys(gpx));
    console.log('GPX layers:', gpx._layers);

    // ... other code ...

    var startPoint = gpx.get_start_point(); // This line throws an error
    
    if (startPoint) {
        // Handle start point
    } else {
        console.error('Could not find start point in GPX data');
    }

    console.log('GPX loaded and bounds set');
}).addTo(map);

Here are the console error log I'm seeing:
Uncaught TypeError: gpx.get_start_point is not a function 
 at https://cdpn.io/cpe/boomboom/pen.js?key=pen.js-cde078dc-6641-a722-b945-faa0a118c352:107

The GPX file seems to load successfully, as indicated by the "GPX loaded and bounds set" message. The gpx object is created, and it has methods and layers. However, when trying to call gpx.get_start_point(), I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: gpx.get_start_point is not a function".
Codepen: https://codepen.io/mrsamlj/pen/qBzKEVV?editors=1111
Questions:

Why isn't the get_start_point() method available on the GPX object?

Is this method deprecated or removed in newer versions of the Leaflet-GPX plugin?

What's the recommended way to get the start point of a GPX route using the latest version of the Leaflet-GPX plugin?

If get_start_point() is no longer available, what's the best alternative to extract the start point from the GPX data?


